# SQL - Select rows from two different tables

Tags: sql, mysql

Having this table

```
Table "Items"

itemID
itemTitle
itemContent
```

and this

```
Table "MyList"

userID
itemID
deleted
```

how can I select all rows from table "Items" and showing the field "deleted", even if the itemID do not exist in "MyList", given an userID?

Example of the query result:

```
itemID | itemTitle | deleted | userID
-------------------------------------
1      | Title1    | 1       | 2
2      | Title2    | 0       | 2
3      | Title3    | (null)  | (null)
4      | Title4    | (null)  | (null)
```

What would be the query, so that I can get that result?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing this, but it returns what I was looking for:

```
select itemID, itemTitle, deleted, userID
FROM(
SELECT i.id_itemID, i.itemTitle, M.deleted, M.userID
FROM
    MyList M
    right OUTER JOIN Items I ON I.itemID= M.itemID
) as MyTableItems
where itemID = 3 or itemID is null
```

Answer (score 16):

```
SELECT I.itemID, I.itemTitle, M.deleted
FROM
    Items I
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MyList M ON M.itemID = I.itemID
WHERE M.userID = 9
```

**Edit:** Based on OP's comment:

```
SELECT I.itemID, I.itemTitle, M.deleted, M.userID
FROM
    MyList M
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Items I ON I.itemID = M.itemID
WHERE M.userID = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outer join`:

```
select a.itemId, a.itemTitle, b.deleted
from Items a left outer join MyList b
on a.itemId = b.itemId
```