# How to get the questions and its related tags using store procedure in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, stored-procedures, tags

I have a `questions` table with

1. id
2. title
3. body

**And**

A `tags` table with

1. id
2. name
3. description

**And finally a `question_tags` relation table with**

1. id
2. tag_id
3. question_id

I have the below code to get all the questions using mysql store procedures .

> I need to get the question details  and its related tag details using a store procedures (like this `<question details,tag1 details,tag2 details... tag5 details>`).
>   
> I thought about storing the tag's id along with the question table ,but for retrieving the tag details I had to write another query which store procedure doesn't allow me to do.Same issue when trying to get tag details after getting the question id.
>   I tried my level best ,but yet don't know how to solve it.
>   **any ideas or suggestions?** **thanks**
>   
>   I tried my best to explain the situation .

Comment: What are you trying to do in the end? Do you want to select the questions, and associated tags all in the same query?

Comment: requirement is not clear. Would you post some sample input output?

Comment: @Kenyon. I jus want to display the results like stackoverflow does.

Comment: @1000111 ,I tried my best to explain the situation.

Comment: @Sachin, I am reasonably sure this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/532706/3158829

Comment: so is it your expected output structure `<question details, tag1 details,tag2 details,....,tagN details>` @Sachin?

Comment: @Kenyon , sorry that's not I wanted,its about two tables in that question,where as in my case its three tables.

Comment: is the number of tags constant in nature or growing? If it's constant then how many tags do you have? Otherwise you need `dynamic pivoting`.

Comment: @1000111, max 5 tags , "dynamic pivoting"  never heard of it .

Comment: Have you found any solution yet? @Sachin

Comment: nope ,thanks for the effort .I am trying to understand your code right now.

Comment: can you add some descriptions so that me and others can understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic query for finding out the output structure like below:

```
 question_id    title   FirstTagName    FirstTag    SecondTagName   SecondTag   ThirdTagName    ThirdTag    FourthTagName   FourthTag   FifthTagName    FifthTag
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
t.question_id,
t.title,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 1 THEN t.name END) AS FirstTagName,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 1 THEN t.description END) AS FirstTag,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 2 THEN t.name END) AS SecondTagName,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 2 THEN t.description END) AS SecondTag,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 3 THEN t.name END) AS ThirdTagName,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 3 THEN t.description END) AS ThirdTag,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 4 THEN t.name END) AS FourthTagName,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 4 THEN t.description END) AS FourthTag,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 5 THEN t.name END) AS FifthTagName,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 5 THEN t.description END) AS FifthTag
FROM
(
    SELECT
        question_id,
        questions.title,
        tag_id,
        tags. NAME,
        tags.description,
        IF (@prev = question_id ,@c := @c + 1,@c := 1) constantTagNumber,
        @prev := question_id
    FROM    (   SELECT @prev := 0 ,@c := 1) var,    questions_tags
    INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = questions_tags.tag_id
    INNER JOIN questions ON questions_tags.question_id = questions.ID
    ORDER BY    question_id,    tag_id
) t
GROUP BY t.question_id;
```

[**======>DEMO HERE<======**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/996731/1/0)

**Explanation:**

First look at the inner query:

```
SELECT
            question_id,
            questions.title,
            tag_id,
            tags. NAME,
            tags.description,
            IF (@prev = question_id ,@c := @c + 1,@c := 1) constantTagNumber,
            @prev := question_id
        FROM    (   SELECT @prev := 0 ,@c := 1) var,    questions_tags
        INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = questions_tags.tag_id
        INNER JOIN questions ON questions_tags.question_id = questions.ID
        ORDER BY    question_id,    tag_id;
```

[**DEMO OF IT**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/996731/6/0)

Look there's no `group by` clause in this query. What I tried to achieve through this query is :

- To get all the questions and tags so that all the records selected
  from `questions_tags` table stick together having increasing number
  of `tag ids` (done by `ORDER BY question_id,tag_id` clause)
- I used two `mysql user variables` (`e.g. @prev and @c`). The question ID is stored in @prev variable. While traversing the rows in `questions_tags` table if I see a new `question_id` then I reset the variable `@c` to `1`.
- The `@c` variable assigns a tag number for the tags.id field which is irrespective of the original `tag_number`. Since you told that there can be infinite number of `tags` but each question can have at most five tags so the range of variable `@c` will be `1 to 5` `i.e. [1,5]`.
- The inner query generates this [**result set**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/996731/6/0)
- Now the outer query comes into play. There's a `group by` clause in the outer most query. So you will get a single row for each question.
- `MAX(CASE WHEN t.constantTagNumber = 1 THEN t.name END)` the role of this line is to ensure that the first tag description will be put in the corresponding column in the final result set. It's called `pivoting`.

Please spend some time looking on the inner query. Then think yourself "How can I generate the final result set from this table?".

If you need any help then feel free to ask.

Comment: can you add some descriptions so that me and others can understand it.

Comment: tag_id varies from 0 --> infinity.  But how it works if the tag_id is compared only with 1-->5 id values .Am I missing something ?

Comment: I can add explanation. But you told me earlier that there are max 5 tags in your tags table. So that I assumed tag id range is [1,5]. Doesn't this query fulfill your need?

Comment: max five tags for each question like in stackoverflow . Please check my table schema , there will be more than one questions and so more than 5 tags.

Comment: @Sachin, I've changed the query so that it conforms to your requirement hopefully. Please check now. Please check the **SQL FIDDLE** DEMO.

Comment: By seeing the code above I understand that , I know hardly nothing about mysql. I think its what I needed , can you add some descriptions.

Comment: Does it work for you? Okay I can add explanation later. After adding I will let you know. Right now passing busy time doing office works. Sorry dude! @Sachin

Comment: added explanation @Sachin. Please check now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time that you spend for answering.

Comment: Have another doubt , is this an efficient way for building schema for storing tags and the question-tag relation and all , or is there any other way ( assuming there is millions of tags and questions)

Comment: I think the table structures are okay. Because it's `many to many` relation. That's how `many to many` relations are handled. No need to worry.