# select statments not working

Tags: php, mysqli

**problem occurred while creting comment system for my web site**

select statement not working

```
   $reslt = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tbl_users where id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
  $row= mysqli_fetch_array($reslt);

   $comm = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tbl_comments where id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
     While(  $row= mysqli_fetch_array($comm))

 {
    $comm[] = $row;
 }
```

if i remove second statement ($comm) first statement works fine

**My second question**

how can i fetch data from database in php ?

**Here is the code**

```
 $comm = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tbl_comments where id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
   While(  $row= mysqli_fetch_array($comm))

{
    $comm[] = $row;
}
```

Not getting results (comments)

```
  echo $row['comment'];
```

Comment: Read up on [table joining](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - Select rows from two different tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532694/sql-select-rows-from-two-different-tables)

Comment: *"if i remove second statement ($comm) first statement works fine"* - Something failed then; check for errors.

Comment: i dont know why getting down votes

Comment: @MadhuMunna Proper form is to only ask 1 question per post.  Also, your 1st "question" is not really expressed as a question (e.g. "How do I do ____?" or "Why is my output ____ when my input is ____?").  Lastly, very basic questions (e.g. "how can i fetch data from database in php?") have probably already been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure of your schema, but perhaps something like this:

```
$result = $connection->query("
SELECT 
  C.comment AS comment, U.user AS user
FROM 
  tbl_comments C, tbl_users U 
WHERE 
  C.id = U.id
");

while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo"$data[comment] by $data[user] </br>";
}
```

Comment: got Fatal error:  on a non-object in  while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

Comment: It depends on your schema. Can you edit your original post to show how your tables are structured?