# mysql result in two columns from same table without duplicate rows

Tags: mysql

I don't know how to ask this correctly - it was probably asked many times.
I have two tables. Companies and budgets.

Companies [id,name,address]
Budgets [id,company_id,year,budget]

I want to create a select where I would get the result for each company and budgets for each year in the same row.

budgets table:

```
id | company_id | year | budget  
1  | 1          | 2018 | 1500   
2  | 1          | 2019 | 2500  
3  | 2          | 2018 | 700  
4  | 2          | 2019 | 6000
```

So I would like to get the budgets in year columns

```
SELECT
a.id,
a.`name`,
IF(b.season_id = 1,b.budget,'') AS "budget 2018",
IF(b.season_id = 2,b.budget,'') AS "budget 2019"

FROM companies AS a
INNER JOIN budgets AS b ON a.id = b.company_id
```

This of course returns double rows. :)

```
company name | budget 2018 | budget 2019  
company one  | 1500        | 
company one  |             | 2500  
company two  | 700         | 
company two  |             | 6000
```

How can I get the budgets in the same row?

```
company name | budget 2018 | budget 2019  
company one  | 1500        | 2500  
company two  | 700         | 6000
```

Or how is this procedure called/described so I can ask uncle google? :)

Edit:
I got suggestions for solving this task with outer joins. Truthfully I haven't had the time to solve the problem with outer joins - not yet confident if I can trust the result. The other thing is that I find the title of the suggested solution somewhat misleading. I ended solving this problem with the use of "fake" aggregates. Because this is a task I need once a year for a custom export I won't be pursuing a "better" solution. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - Select rows from two different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532694/sql-select-rows-from-two-different-tables)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I got it working with "fake" max agregate. In my case there are no empty rows. The problem was that the rows duplicated for every instance of budget year. I think there is a working solution with outer join but I haven't had the time for learning a new trick. Anyway thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
  c.id,
  c.name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN b.season_id = 1 THEN b.budget END) AS `budget 2018`,
  MAX(CASE WHEN b.season_id = 2 THEN b.budget END) AS `budget 2019`
FROM companies AS c INNER JOIN budgets AS b 
ON c.id = b.company_id
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

I use `MAX()` because in your sample data there is only 1 row for each company/year.
If this is not the case and you want the total for each company/year then use `SUM()`.

Comment: Hi I think your soltion is better than just (fake) SUM because I actually have multiple table with budgets (different budget types).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a (fake) aggrgation function

```
    SELECT
    a.id,
    a.`name`,
    sum(IF(b.season_id = 1,b.budget,'')) AS `budget 2018`,
    sum(IF(b.season_id = 2,b.budget,'')) AS `budget 2019`
    FROM companies AS a
    INNER JOIN budgets AS b ON a.id = b.company_id
    GROUP BY a.id, a.name
```

Comment: You could use NULL instead of '' in the IF-clause to avoid unnecessary datatype conversions from numeric to char and back to numeric.

Comment: Hi I tried both and get the same correct results with both. This is used once a year for an export so optimisation is not key here. But thank you for the additional explanaton.

Comment: A ran across another problem. I actually have multiple budget types in additional tables so if I add another budget table the values get doubled where there is another budget in the second budget table. So this solution is ok for one "budgets" table.

Comment: anyway each aggreagation function return the same result ....sum()... max() ...min().... ... the concept is the same

Answer (score 0):

probably this is what you wanted to know.

[SQL - Select rows from two different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532694/sql-select-rows-from-two-different-tables)

use outer join

```
INNER JOIN budgets AS b ON a.id = b.company_id
```

to

```
outer join budgets AS b ON a.id = b.comapny_id
```